# Difference between an electromagnetic calorimeter and a pet-detector

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors, medical-physics

Is there a conceptual-technical difference between an [electromagnetic calorimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter_(particle_physics)) and a [pet-detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography)?
Surprisingly I couldn't find a better/rough concept of an Ecal but ultimately it consists of a lot of crystals and electronics readout like a pet-detector does. So are they conceptually the same and just tailored for (not so much) different purposes? Or are there also major technical differences?

**Ecal**

[image: img1]

**PET**
[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

From searching the internet I see that a PET detector is a

> [Polyethylene Terephthalate (PET)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168583X16000598) Nuclear Track Detector (NTD)

It is true that any detector has to use electromagnetic interactions to finally detect the signature of particles in high energy experiments. An electromagnetic calorimeter's  crystals are chosen so  that all charged particles leave a track passing through, but electrons leave all their energy ( the maximum known from the beam energies) in the calorimeter.

See [this plot](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2120661) of the [CMS detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Muon_Solenoid):

[image]

The electromagnetic calorimeter was designed back in 1998, and if you have the patience to go through the [technical report](https://cds.cern.ch/record/349375/files/ECAL_TDR.pdf) for its construction you will find the reasons they chose *Lead Tungstate Crystals* . From the number of authors and the complexity of the calorimeter it is not a simple detector that is planned.

> [To exploit the  full  range of  TeV-scale  physics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4101392_Precision_lead_tungstate_Crystal_calorimeter_for_CMS_at_LHC)  at LHC  the CMS detector is designed with emphasis on clean identification and precision measurements of electrons, muons, and photons.Combined with good jet and missing energy measurements, the detector has excellent physics potential. The design goal of the CMS detector is to measure electrons, photons and muons with an energy resolution of better than 1% over a large momentum range.

The particular crystals were chosen for radiation hardness (not to be easily destroyed) which would not be true for the polyethylene crystals.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a bit confused. A PET device is (usually) a positron-electron-tomogrophy which is detecting (only?) photons from decays of substances inside a human body. And an electromagnetic calorimeter is also designed to detect photons (though not from a human body). But are they actually conceptually-technically different? Or are they just using different crystal material?